# Converting spaces (all) to tabs in UltraEdit not working?

Tags: ultraedit

Am I missing something? I have a 1000-line file which contains space-separated rows of two fields. I selected menu *Format* -> *Spaces to Tabs (All)* and nothing happened. I tried several times.

This is the Mac version of UltraEdit on [OS X Mavericks (10.9)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name *Spaces to Tabs* is perhaps a little misleading. The function maintains the absolute positions of the existing text, inserting as many TABs as possible and padding with space to maintain the position of the existing text. This leads to TABs being present in perhaps unexpected places and no TABs in other places.

### Example

Consider the following three lines of text (there are two leading spaces in each line, and I have added position and tab stop indications above and below for a tab stop setting of four):

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         1         2         3         4
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
--------------------------------------------------
  Stack Overflow          169  (no change)
  Server Fault            246  (no change)
  Meta Stack Overflow      269
--------------------------------------------------
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
```

After menu command *Spaces to Tabs* is run, the text appears in *exactly the same positions*. But there is now a TAB between `Stack` and `Overflow` (as there is a tab stop at position 9). There are two TABs and two spaces between `Overflow` and `169` (two TABs to get to the tab stop position at 25 and then two spaces to get to position 27 where `169` starts). There aren't any TABs between `169` and `(` as there aren't any tab stops at position 30, 31 and 32. And so on.

## Resolution?

Depending on your data you may be able to make it work by adjusting the tab stop number to something other than 4. If you set it to 1 you *will* get some TABS, but perhaps too many. It is set by menu command *Advanced* -> *Configuration* -> *Editor* -> *Word Wrap / Tab Settings* -> *Tab Stop Value*:

[image: Screenshot of UltraEdit's configuration dialog]

Or you may be better off using the search/replace function and, if needed, a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: Yes, i resorted to a regular expression.  In any case thx for the answer - confirming there is not a direct implementation in the editor.